# Accept download alert message pop up in Katalon Studio

Tags: web-testing, katalon-studio

I create automated testing by click on download button to download file (.pdf, .xlsx, .exe, .application) but every download, it showed the pop up dialog to confirm.

So, how to access this pop up or let it download automatically without asking?

[image]

[image]

I try to add reference in execution and run it by opening browser and click download, but it still show that dialog message.

**For Chrome**

[image]

**Log view (chrome)**
[image]

**For Firefox**

[image]

**Log view (firefox)**
[image]

**Or Set Reference by this way (still not working)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set these preferences under `Project -> Settings -> Execution -> Default -> WebUI -> Chrome`.

Variable `prefs` has to be created and values below has to be added to array.

> browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting : Boolean : false
>
> safebrowsing.enabled : Boolean : false
>
> browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk : String :
> application/download,
> application/octet-stream, text/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msexcel, application/x-msexcel, application/excel, application/pdf
>
> safebrowsing-disable-download-protection : Boolean : true

You can read more about Desired Capabilities in [Execution settings](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Execution+Settings).

Comment: It's not working.
it's still see the confirm pop up.

Comment: @KimRamin : I added preference `safebrowsing.enabled`. Please set this too. I can't reproduce this on my site, but it should work.

Comment: Are these preferences support all browsers Or can use only with chrome?

Comment: @KimRamin : These are for Chrome. I updated answer, sorry, I missed logical value, it has to be false.

Comment: if these are for Chrome, how about other browsers especially IE, Is it use another reference? @plaidshirt

Comment: @KimRamin : Is it working for Chrome? If yes, please test it with other browser too.

Comment: It's still not working, Are there any other way to make it?

Comment: @KimRamin : I updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: thanks for updated your answer but It's still not working. see my update question with log view. @plaidshirt

Comment: @KimRamin : As I see log doesn't contain information about this issue.

Comment: I don't know, but when I add reference, It's always show that log view (red line) like that, and if I remove reference that log view information is not visible anymore. that's why I screenshot that log view and it' easy for you to identify the issue.  @plaidshirt

Answer (score 0):

Also struggled a bit. I've got the chrome answer still searching for Firefox answer.
For Chrome add a property with the following:
Name: prefs
Type: Dictionary
Value: {download.prompt_for_download=false}
If you want to specify the download directory you can add the value to the Dictionary: {download.default_directory}

[image]

You can also check out this site [Capabilities & ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) for Chrome's capabilities.